# How to override inline CSS (specifically a div with certain class) with external CSS?

Tags: css, overriding, inline

I'm trying to fix an alignment issue that's caused by a row of social media share buttons, specifically the code generated by the Google+ button. I didn't set this site up and I'm not sure how the button was implemented, only know that it was part of an AddThis plugin or something.

The Google+ button seems to automatically generate a div with inline CSS styling:

```
<div class="google_plusone_iframe_widget" style="width:90px;height:25px;">
```

I need to get rid of the width and height, but how can I override it externally? I've tried the following but it didn't work:

```
div.google_plusone_iframe_widget[style] {width:auto!important; height:auto!important;}
```

Does anyone know how I can do that? Thank you in advance! Here is the page for reference, I am referring to the top left social media buttons:

http://www.canadianoutback.com/events/crime_investigators.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS selector should be:

```
.google_plusone_iframe_widget {width:auto !important; height:auto !important;}
```

Remove that [style] attribute in your selector, and there's no need to specify the `div` tag.

[image]

Comment: Thanks .. I've tried this before but it still doesn't work, because then this code just gets overwritten by the inline CSS that gets auto-generated. And I did notice the typo (missing T at the end), still does not work.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's the point. That's what I am trying to do. I can't just delete the [style] attribute because that code is auto-generated inline by the AddThis Google+ social media button. I am trying to get rid of the width and height it autogenerates through using external CSS to override it.

Comment: I was refering to [style] in your selector.

Comment: If you're not planning on changing that button later on, you can temporarily fix your problem with .addthis_button_google_plusone { width: 24px; height: 16px; overflow: hidden; }

Comment: That's what I thought you meant .. but yes I tried removing [style] selector and it did not work .. also tried your other temporary fix but that did not work either :(

Comment: Try using  !important on width and height in the temporal fix.

Comment: I'm literally pasting my answer to screen.css and it works. Are you sure you are using your updated stylesheet?

Comment: I am :( when I make other edits it works ... I used:
    .addthis_button_google_plusone { width: 24px!important; height: 16px!important; overflow: hidden; }

Comment: The first solution should work: .google_plusone_iframe_widget {width:auto!important; height:auto!important;} ...  Try deleting your cache and reloading the website.

Comment: Thank you, you were right it was a caching issue and your code did work! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked, there's just one more thing, I don't know if using !important without using a space before affects across browsers, honestly it was a typo since I copy-pasted from your question, please add a space between auto and !important, I edited my answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this code `#leftNav .addthis_toolbox .google_plusone_iframe_widget {width:auto!important; height:auto!important;}` to make it.

Comment: Thanks .. I just tried it but unfortunately still not working :(

Answer (score 1):

Could please try this once `#leftNav a.addthis_button_google_plusone .google_plusone_iframe_widget[style] {width:auto!important; height:auto!important;}`

Comment: Thanks again .. still no luck however :(

Answer (score 1):

Please do try with this

```
 #leftNav a.addthis_button_google_plusone.at300b .google_plusone_iframe_widget {
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is inside iframe we can't apply any style or script for it.